# Descomponer número con una función recursiva

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente enunciado:

> Crea una función recursiva que implemente un algoritmo que imprime
>   todos los posibles descomposiciones d'un nombre natural como suma de
>   nombres menores que el.
>
> Ejemplos:
>
> Si introduce 1: 1 = 1
>
> Si introduce el 2: 2 = 1 + 1
>
> Si introduce el 3: 3 = 1 + 1 + 1
>
> Si introduce el 4: 4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

No entiendo como funciona la recrusvidad, de momento tengo esto :

```
def ex3(num):
    if num==1:
        return 1
    else:
        print(num,"= ",end=" ")
        return ex3(num-1)
```

No entiendo cómo puedo hacer que llame a la función y que me muestre solo unos.

Salduos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ex3(num):
   return ex3_aux(num)

def ex3_aux(num):
   if num == 1:
       return "1"
   else:
        num = num - 1
        return "%s + %s" % (ex3_aux(num) , "1")

 print(ex3(4))
```

la recursividad consiste en definir una función en términos de sí misma, en la solución que te planteo utilizo inmersión y recursividad.

Comment: Muchas gracias.